# Implementing ResultSet interface from a generic SOAP request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to create with an object implementing the Java ResultSet interface getting the data from a generic SOAP request(i need to work on an higher level with both these SOAP result sets and with JDBC result sets).

As i wrote in the title, the SOAP request can be generic: it depends on the parameters passed and can consume different web services, so I know only at runtime the wsdl and the structure the SOAP service is going to deliver me.

I've been trying to figure out in the last few days how to do this, I've come out with few ideas:

1- converting the SOAP body into an xml WebRowSet document, that can be unmarshalled to a WebRowSetImpl class, that implements a WebRowSet interface (interface extending ResultSet).
In this case, I'd have to make customs XSLT on the fly, starting from the WSDL and SOAP response documents.

2- Create Java objects from SOAP response, and then trying to map and fill a generic stub JDBC result set with the data within the java objects

3- Storing all the data from SOAP response into a (normalized or not normalized) database, and then read from the database with any JDBC driver.

Which do you think is best overall the way to go?
And which the simplest way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can or should be done.

I would never want to see anything implementing `ResultSet` escaping out of a persistence tier.  You need to map that into a collection or object and close it in method scope.

What you're really asking for is a generic collection to map the `ResultSet` into.  The best you can is a `Map` of `Lists`, where the keys are column names and the values are `Lists` by columns, or a `List` of `Maps`, where each Map represents one row's worth of column name/value pairs.

Either one is absolutely generic, but there's no contract to it, either.

I think this is a poor way to think about web services.  The good ones usually keep the notion of a contract in mind.  Their functions are narrow and well defined; so are their inputs and outputs.

You sound like you want to be able to send in any SQL query the user wishes and send back whatever the results are.  That's too loose a service for my taste.

A real service owns its data and uses it for its own narrow purposes. No client should have to extract a bunch of stuff, do things, and put it back. Hide all of that inside the service.  Add what those clients are doing to the data to its API and don't let the abstraction leak out.

Read Werner Vogel if you'd like to get a better idea of how to implement a service oriented architecture.

Comment: i exposed only a part of a bigger platform, the full flow is:
1 - extract data from jdbc connectors/soap services
2- transform the temporary data using a common interface (i thought of result set because of this)
3- store persistently the transformed data in a database

Comment: Still sounds too broad and squishy to me.  No contract.  And a real service owns its data and uses it for its own narrow purposes.  No client should have to extract a bunch of stuff, do things, and put it back.  Hide all of that inside the service and don't let the abstraction leak out.  You'll regret a design like this in the future.

Comment: I am not putting back the data i got with jdbc connectors or soap, i just extract them from various sources, define combination/transformation logic from within my platform and then store the results of combination/transformation in my platform. It's kind of a ETL

Comment: I don't think this is a good design for ETL.  Use an appropriate tool and have it access the database directly.  Why add a service and go through another network hop?

Comment: Because we have several data sources, and we would like to aggregate them for business intelligence reports..

Comment: ETL tools are what you need, not web services.  I'd have your report aggregator pull from a database without connecting to an intermediate web service.  It makes more sense, and it'll perform better.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need to either get data:

.1. from *relational database* via `JDBC`

or

.2. from *web service* via `SOAP` requests

`ResultSet` interface is part of `JDBC` which is suited to work **ONLY** with *relational databases* and **definitely NOT** with *web services*. That's why it looks like you want to use wrong tool for your task.

The right way would be to either:

.1. Write your own high-level abstraction which abstracts from both *relational databases* and *web services* as data sources (do not confuse with `javax.sql.DataSource` class) and then provide two implementations: one which works with *relational database* using `JDBC` and another which works with *web service* processing `SOAP` requests.

.2. Use some existing framework for doing this if exists. Though I'm not sure, but you may check http://www.smooks.org/ - maybe it has something related.

If you **really don't have any choice** and **must** work with data sources using only `JDBC` interface - I think the most simpler way would be your 3rd suggestion though it will have a lot of drawbacks (e.g. *bad performance*)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am already writing an high-level abstraction, but I designed to use the WebRowSet or something similar as the high-level data structure, I thought it would save me a conversion from the JDBC extractor (only 1 conversion soap->high level instead of 2 to do) and also the interface offered the methods I needed.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting solution - didn't know about `WebRowSet` and as per following tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/webrowset.html it may be what you need, though with XSLT it may be quite cumbersome. Good luck with that anyway:)